# Scala - How to get Array[Byte] from scala.io.Source

Tags: scala

I have an instance of `scala.io.BufferedSource` (retrieved from `scala.io.Source`) and want to get raw bytes out of it. Most of the answers found on the internet use `getLines` method which disregards new-line delimiters. I need to retrieve the contents as-is and the API seems rather complicated. What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Have you considered using Java's `Files.readAllBytes(...)`?

Comment: Well, that thing is just an iterator so you can just call `toArray` but note that loafing a whole file in memory is usually a bad idea. Why do you need the contents as a big `Array[Byte]`?

Comment: @GaëlJ I'm reading resources, not real files.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez it iterates over `Char`, not `Byte`. Loading into memory is fine for my usecase

Comment: @RA that's not an issue at all. It needs a `Path` which can refer to resources part of the classpath.

Comment: @RA okay fair, I shouldn't have assumed it was a file. Although my question remains, why an `Array[Byte]` that is a weird type, even more for a resource? Anyways, I think you may either `map` the `Iterator` to get the `Byte` of each `Char` or maybe just do it **Java** way using `Class` and `InputStream`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez There is nothing "weird" about `Array[Byte]`. Casting chars to bytes would generally lose data. Java way would not be optimal for my cross-platform code

Comment: _"Casting chars to bytes would generally lose data"_ not if you do it in a proper way, probably needing a `flatMap` rather than `map` - Anyways, `Source` is using `Class` and `InputStream` under the surface so either there is no cross-platform issue or it is already there. And yes, I still think `Array[Byte]` is pretty weird but whatever you say. I would also just use **fs2** but anyways, good luck.

Comment: "_Source is using Class and InputStream under the surface so either there is no cross-platform issue or it is already there_"
That I didn't.know

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this:

```scala
val bs: BufferedSource = scala.io.Source.fromURL(new URI("https://google.com").toURL)

val result: Array[Byte] = bs.map(_.toByte).toArray
```

Comment: This breaks on multi-byte unicode characters